# Hot Module Replacement not working with Mac / Vagrant

Tags: macos, vagrant, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr

I'm using the latest (v3) [react-redux-starter-kit](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit). Everything went fine, a new project is set up except the HMR: It does not reload, I can't see my changes. I checked the browser's console: `[HMR] connected`

After some more investigation I figured out that if I make the change inside the Vagrant box (logged in) HMR does work! So it must be a filesystem-level issue between the host machine (Mac OSX) and the Vagrant box.

Has anyone had this issue before?

**UPDATE:**
I found and installed a Vagrant plugin called [vagrant-notify-forwarder](https://github.com/mhallin/vagrant-notify-forwarder). Now it should be forwarding the fs events to the guest system. But HMR still out of order ... In [this thread](http://www.ecyrd.com/ButtUgly/) someone mentioned that only the ATTRIB changes are sent to the guest system. I'm not sure if thats enough for the HMR ...

**UPDATE 2:**
I'm trying to set up another tool called Guard/Listen. If anybody knows how to use it that'd probably solve this question. But for me no luck so far ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution! With [vagrant-notify-forwarder](https://github.com/mhallin/vagrant-notify-forwarder) now it forwards the fs events to the guest system. (At first, it wasn't working .. I had to try the core [notify-forwarder](https://github.com/mhallin/notify-forwarder) to check for errors and it turned out that its client did not run on Debian due to gcc6 issues ... after trying it with Ubuntu it finally worked)